# Why does indexing a Numpy int array cause "TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable"?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a Python program that is failing with the error:

`TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable`

I understand what the message means, but I do not understand why it applies because I am trying to index a Numpy 2D `int` array, using a two-tuple `(row,col)` as the index.

Here is the code and I've put a large <<<==== arrow next to the line that is getting the error message; can you please explain what's going wrong and how to fix it? I think it might be related to the lind I put `$$$$` next to.

```py
import numpy as np

# An "island" is a 4-connected component of 0 cells, and a "closed island"
# is an island surrpounded on all sides by 1's.  An "open island" is an
# island NOT surrounded on all sides by 1's, which is (I hope) equivalent
# to having at least one cell adjacent to the grid border.  A cell is
# indexed by a 2-tuple (row,col)

class Solution:

    def closedIsland(self, grid: list[list[int]]) -> int:
        nrows = len( grid )
        ncols = len( grid[ 0 ] )
        conn_comp = self.ConnectedComponents( nrows, ncols )
        # Gather the connected components of 0's (!)
        for irow in range( nrows ):
            for icol in range( ncols ):
                if grid[ irow ][ icol ] == 1:
                    continue
                conn_comp.onborder = irow == 0 or irow == nrows - 1 or icol == 0 or icol == ncols - 1  $$$$
                # Look North
                if irow > 0 and grid[ irow - 1][ icol ] == 0:
                    conn_comp.union( ( irow, icol ), ( irow - 1, icol ) )
                # Look West
                if icol > 0 and grid[ irow ][ icol - 1 ] == 0:
                    conn_comp.union( ( irow, icol ), ( irow, icol - 1 ) )

        return 0


    class ConnectedComponents:
        def __init__( self, nrows, ncols ):
            self.parent = np.zeros( ( nrows, ncols ), dtype = object )
            for row in range( nrows ):
                for col in range( ncols ):
                    self.parent[ row, col ] = ( row, col )
            self.size = np.zeros( ( nrows, ncols ), dtype = int )
            self.onborder = np.zeros( ( nrows, ncols ), dtype = int )
            print( "type(self.onborder)", type( self.onborder ), "self.onborder", self.onborder )
        def find( self, rowcol ):
            while rowcol != self.parent[ rowcol ]:
                rowcol = self.parent[ rowcol ]
            return rowcol
        def union( self, rowcol_1, rowcol_2 ):
            comp1 = self.find( rowcol_1 )
            comp2 = self.find( rowcol_2 )
            print( "comp1", comp1, "comp2", comp2 )
            if self.size[ comp1 ] >= self.size[ comp2 ]:
                self.parent[ comp2 ] = comp1
                self.size[ comp1 ] += self.size[ comp2 ]
                self.onborder[ comp1 ] += self.onborder[ comp2 ]     <<<===========
            else:
                self.parent[ comp1 ] = comp2
                self.size[ comp2 ] += self.size[ comp1 ]
                self.onborder[ comp2 ] += self.onborder[ comp1 ]


grid = [[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],[1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0],[1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0],[1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]]
print( "result", Solution().closedIsland( grid ) )
```

Comment: Look for the place where you're setting `onborder` to a bool. It's not hard to find.

Comment: the `<<<====` is a poor substitute for full traceback, since we have scroll down and across to find it.  In any case you may think that the variable is an array, but the code knows it's a scalar, a `bool`.  Which are we supposed to believe?  Even as an experienced programmer, I don't depend on my guesses or assumptions.